# deep dive implementation documentation

Tags: tangle, documentation

I want to explore, how the iota tangle works, how it is implemented and what can be done with it.
After reading the whitepaper, I now serch for technical documentation, that makes a deep dive possible.
Is there any site where such documentation is listed on?